# How can I change the default browser and pdf viewer in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser, pdf-reader

Normally when I use for example firefox, chrome or foxit reader the "do you want to set this as the default browser/reader" works. But since upgrading windows 8.1 to windows 10 I'm stuck with IE and the windows pdf reader despite clicking yes when that question pops up..

My question is here: How can I change this? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: This link explains how to change the browser to Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-your-default-browser-windows-10

Comment: Control Panel>Default Programs

Comment: For chrome it worked tnx. Although the foxit reader isnt to be found there oO